# Data Migration Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4.2

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.2.4, delta-migration

Database is 20 Go. 3 m + SKUs. What Data Migration tool should I use ? Also, can I migrate Data from Live server or should I use Data from a non Live backup server ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data Migration from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351865/data-migration-from-magento-1-9-to-magento-2-4-2)

Comment: That is my own question from yesterday. Got no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1 - You can use official migration tool from Magento [Link](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/releases/tag/2.4.2)

Second, You should always run dry migration on copy of live database, so it will give all possible error and you can find corresponding solution of those errors.

For more detail you can refer [migration tool document](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/bk-migration-guide.html)

Hope above will help!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to upgrade my store from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.4.2 too and someone here recommended these guys to me: Magento Tool, cart2cart, litextension, and pelican commerce. In the end, I decided to go with litextension and the service was great. You can check out their service [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/litextension-magento-to-magento-migration.html) or contact them to see if they can help with your project.

As far as I know, you can migrate your data from either your live server or your backup server. It’s just that you should prepare backup data just in case your migration has errors and you need to track them down.

Comment: Thanks Fiona. Why did you not do with official migration tool from Magento ?
Is there a problem with it ?

Comment: I did consider Magento's official migration tool actually, I am not quite technically skilled. Then I would've had to carry out the whole project myself and it would've been too much for me to handle. I think it was better for me to enlist professional help to achieve my desired results.